# unixODBC Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Tags: laravel-5, db2-luw

I'm trying to connect to a `db2` server from my `Laravel` application. Since `Laravel` doesn't support `db2` out of the box, I tried using this package https://github.com/cooperl22/laravel-db2, which requires me to install `odbc` driver.

So far, I've been able to install `odbc` using the following command:
`apt-get install php-odbc`

However, it seems like my `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/odbcinst.ini` configuration are still wrong. and here's the full error message when I tried to run `php artisan migrate`:

```
[PDOException]                                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default   
  driver specified
```

Here's my `/etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[db2]
Description=DB2 Server
Driver=db2
Database=mydb
```

and here's my `/etc/odbcisnt.ini`:

```
[db2]
Description = DB2 database access
Driver = /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/lib64/libdb2.so
FileUsage = 1
DontDLClose = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your environment variables are set correctly. As shown on [this link](http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/db2.html), make sure the following is set:

```
export DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
isql -v sample db2inst1 ibmdb2
```

Exerpt from the unixodbc.org page I linked to above:

> Then when it comes to connecting, you MUST have the environment
>   variable DB2INSTANCE set to a vaild db2 instance, so for instance to
>   connect with isql

Both of your config files look correct to me. (The isql part was just an example to test connectivity.)

Comment: I got a weird error message that says : `[001][nxDC[B]CIDie]SL03 Tedtbs la aeo aaaenm SML"cudntb on. QSAE475` And then `[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect`. Are you familiar with the first error? It seems like I'm maknig progress

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like progress in the fact that it's a different error, but that looks like some kind of encoding or language issue now, or perhaps a library version issue. I've never seen that before either...